# Perl:download DBD::AnyData

Tags: perl, perl-module, activestate

Can someone help me with a download link for DBD::AnyData perl module. I installed ActivePerl and when it was time to export data from a CSV file into a database using AnyData I realised that the DBD::AnyData module was not found. I tried downloading it from the cpan website but after several attempts there was no success,the browser keeps saying "Server down or have been moved". I would like to get a different link to enable me download this module.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not using package managers like PPM or cpan? PPM is included in ActivePerl.

```
ppm install DBD::AnyData
```

See [manual](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl) or [FAQ](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.16/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html)